# ExtensionFailed JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have a little problem with my code. So I wrote a system that uses JSON files, everything worked fine until I changed one little thing.
This was the code before where everything worked fine:

```
server = {
                "guildid": ctx.guild.id,
                "channelid": ctx.channel.id,
                "invite": f'{(await ctx.channel.create_invite()).url}'
            }
            servers["servers"].append(server)
            with open('servers.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(servers, f, indent=4)
```

After I changed the code to this:

```
server = {
                "guildid": ctx.guild.id,
                "channelid": ctx.channel.id,
                "invite": f'{(await ctx.channel.create_invite()).url}'
            }
            self.servers["servers"].append(server)
            with open('servers.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(self.servers, f, indent=4)
```

I got the error:

```
Exception has occurred: ExtensionFailed JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And since then, nothing worked even after I changed it back.

You guys may have an Idea how to fix this? Never really worked with JSON before.
Have a nice day!

Comment: maybe move `(await ctx.channel.create_invite()).url` to it's own variable and then refer to that variable in the dictionary

Comment: Could you include more of the code to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Eh... it had something to do with the dic so I'm sorry for disturbing. Thanks to all the people who commented! Have a nice day.